# Virtualbox withdebian host/guest failing with NFS

Tags: nfs, vagrant

I have the following vagrant script:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/debian-8.2-64-puppet"

    config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 4096
    v.cpus = 1
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update && install nfs-common portmap
    apt-get install -y puppet 

    puppet module install puppetlabs/stdlib
  SHELL

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"    
    puppet.manifests_path = ".vagrant/puppet"
    puppet.module_path = ".vagrant/puppet/modules"
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", :nfs => true
end
```

When I enable NFS (which I require as the default shared folder causes issues with another program) I get the following errors:

```
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
● nfs-kernel-server.service - LSB: Kernel NFS server support
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2016-07-25 14:13:11 CDT; 17h ago
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

set -e
mkdir -p /var/www
mount -o vers=3,udp 172.28.128.1:/home/alex/Projects/chrome /var/www
if command -v /sbin/init && /sbin/init --version | grep upstart; then
  /sbin/initctl emit --no-wait vagrant-mounted MOUNTPOINT=/var/www
fi


Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

I have ran this script through my IDE and CLI as both myself and a "sudo" user with elevated privileges - still same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem on Arch Linux using VirtualBox as provider and `nfs-utils` installed and enabled.

I spend some time to make it work and can't really tell what exactly made it working in the end. Below I link to the two main resources that I read and tried.

1. Make sure `vagrant` is allowed to run commands as *sudo*. See
   [this link](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1659). (But actually I
   have no user `vagrant` on my system, so this might be superfluos.)
2. Check if `net-tools` are installed. (But this maybe an Arch thing, see [this link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vagrant#.27vagrant_up.27_hangs_on_NFS_mounting_.28Mounting_NFS_shared_folders....29).)